# Sass if statement for angular 2

Tags: css, angular, sass

I need to implement this statement in Sass or CSS:

IF :`host.form-control` IS `.ng-valid[required]` OR `.ng-valid.required`

THEN

```
:host ::ng-deep input.form-control = border-left: 5px solid #42A948;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not an 'Angular' question,
by the way you can try this

```
*:host {
   $self: &;

    &.ng-valid[required], &.ng-valid.required {
      #{$self}::ng-deep input.form-control {
        border-left: 5px solid #42A948;
      }
    }
}
```